# Javascript - Associating a label with an input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, label

I have a webpage with lots of inputs.  They are all in this format, with the input tag before the label.

`<input type='checkbox' id='myinput'>
<label for='myinput'>My Text</label>`

Using javascript, if I didn't want to type `type='checkbox'` each time, I could do this, and each input would become a checkbox...

```
for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;i++) {
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')}
```

I'd like to do the same thing with the label element.  I don't want to use `for='myinputsID'` for every label.  I realize I can nest the inputs inside the label like this to eliminate the `for`,

`<label>My Text
<input type="checkbox" id="myinput">
</label>`

but lets just say I don't want to do that.  I need to keep the html in the same format with the input first and then the label... I would need to find a way to apply the `htmlFor` attribute to each label and assign it the ID of the input immediately preceding it. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you asking to create the input and the label dynamically at run time?

Comment: Not really, because the IDs of the inputs are already known.  So what I'm asking is... is there a way to keep the html in that format, with the input first, then the label.  But not use the FOR in the html.

Comment: So my end result for this example would be...`<input  id="myinput"><label>My Text</label>`  you would need javascript to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to use **document.getElementsByTagName("input")** to get a collection of all the input html elements on your page. Afterwards loop over this list to see which of those are actually checkboxes. If we found a checkbox, we can get the next html element using **element.nextElementSibling**. Finally just set the **htmlFor** attribute for those to the id of the input element.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
  if (elements[a].type == "checkbox") {
    elements[a].nextElementSibling.htmlFor = elements[a].id;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='myinput1'>
<label>My Text</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='myinput2'>
<label>My Text</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='myinput3'>
<label>My Text</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var input;
for (i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
  input = inputs[i];
  input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  input.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('for', input.id);
}
```